# Use Case statement to output value if Specific String + Value are present in row

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I will have thousands of rows with different combinations of the following in [COLUMN1] 
I want to search each row and return a different output depending on the value of W123 if present

COLUMN1:

Row 1: W277(20000.0),W278(50000.0),W290(10000.0),W279(5000.0),W123(10000.0)

Row 2: W277(20000.0),W278(50000.0),W123(20000.0),W279(5000.0)

Row 3: W277(20000.0),W123(30000.0),W278(50000.0),W279(5000.0)

What I have tried:

```
case  
When COLUMN1 ~= "W123(10" then "Pray" 
When COLUMN1 ~= "W123(20" then "THIS" 
When COLUMN1 ~= "W123(30" then "WORKS" 
else "No W123"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your characters:

```
case  
When [COLUMN1]~="W123\\(10" then "Pray" 
When [COLUMN1]~="W123\\(20" then "THIS" 
When [COLUMN1]~="W123\\(30" then "WORKS"
else "No W123"
end
```

Returns this:
[image]

Comment: Thank You so very much, such a simple solution to such a headache of a problem. Really appreciate the help! I hope you have a blessed day and come across a bag of cash next time you go out for a walk.

Comment: @Dragonslayer93 It may not be a bag of cash, but a green check mark indicating this is the answer would be nice! :)